# What would be the best way to document the structure of my pages? Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I do need to document my App, so I'd like to do it in a visual way.

Let's say I have a Login.dart page, and a Home.dart page, so I'd do something like this.

[image]

The thing is, I don't only have that estructure, there are like 3 pages more that are using libraries like FireStore, so I'm not sure what'd be the correct/professional/default way to do it, without make a lot of arrows pointed to the "FireStore rectangle".

How would you do it? Is it there a standar way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: what would be the right way to do this kind of flowchart for App's mobile, if I want document my app what would be the right way of showing them when a page are importing other pages/libraries, without make arrow chaos

Comment: I think there are several ways to document your app. First you can focus on User-Flows by utilizing i.e. a flowchart or sequence diagram where each diagram draws a specific user flow including all necessary components. If you want to depict a more technical documentation you may use UML class diagrams or a high level architecture overview (which means you dont need to draw every arrow).